# iOS MKPolygon pattern

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpolygon

I searched over the internet but I couldn't find an answer to this. Is possible to draw polygon filled with some pattern? I don't wanna use 3rd party libraries. I would like to achieve something similar to this: 
[polygon with pattern](https://statnmap.com/post/2017-04-09-plot-specific-image-delimited-polygon-repeated-pattern-on-map/Wallpaper_in_polygon_Emoji_Header_1024.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

`UIColor` has an initializer for pattern images.

```
guard let image = UIImage(named: "Name of the asset") else { return }
let color = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

Then in your overlay renderer delegate method, you can simply assign it to your fill color.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    // Renderer code

    yourRenderer.fillColor = color

    // Return your renderer

}
```

Comment: Thank You. This allows me for filling polygon with patter but what in case when i would like to fill polygon with pattern and have some background color?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be changing the pattern image's background color.